# How to post rich content from within IDialog.StartAsync() in MS bot framework

Tags: botframework

I am creating a sub-dialog which is called from another dialog. As a first message, I need to post a message with an image and a couple of buttons.

```
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //??? convert context to Activity?
        //then it is trivial to add buttons, images or a HeroCard
        await context.PostAsync(activity);

        context.Done<TestDialog_Start>(this);
    }
```

However, context.PostAsync() only takes either a string or an IMessageActivity object. That's an issue because the first method in the dialog doesn't receive an IMessageActivity object as a parameter (the next method and the subsequent methods do).

Therefore I cannot use something like activity.CreateReply() and I also cannot create a new Activity object because I don't have the From, Recipient, Conversation, ServiceUrl and other data.

How can you get an Activity object from here, or is there any other way to post rich context in an IDialog's first method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so it's weird that it isn't mentioned in Microsoft's documentation, but it seems you can create a fully operational IMessageActivity object from IDialogContext:

```
IMessageActivity activity = context.MakeMessage();
//TODO add text, rich content here
context.PostAsync(activity);
```

Although IMessageActivity is not the same as a fully-functional Activity, it still works well and can use Attachments.

Found it accidentally by browsing class definitions. Before that, wasted several hours writing my own custom function to create an Activity object from a few parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!